# JavaCV FFmpegFrameRecorder not saving / writing to disk

Tags: java, android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm using JavaCV libraries on Android, and I've been able to get the sample Recording activity working somewhat, however it is not writing to disk on my SD card.

Code: https://gist.github.com/ilopez/6046287
Log: https://gist.github.com/ilopez/6046289
Manifest: https://gist.github.com/ilopez/6046296

Unlike [save video using ffmpegframerecorder android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469372/save-video-using-ffmpegframerecorder-android) question, there is no fatal exception.  Just nothing is written to the sdcard.

I have tried the following filenames

/mnt/sdcard/test.flv  - no IO Exception
/sdcard/test.flv - no IO Exception
/idontexist/sdcard/test.flv - IO Exception

I have also tried to place a file in the sdcard folder, nothing saved.

I am confirming the files existence by hooking it up to my computer and viewing the SCH-I535/Card directory.

I also modified the source a bit per my previous question: [How to convert ShortBuffer to Buffer[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764641/how-to-convert-shortbuffer-to-buffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  You cannot read/write data to the SD card when the phone is connected to your PC via USB. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9604364/192577  I found the files I was interested in after removing the SD card and reviewing the file system of the android device.  I found the files I was saving.

Further information about Android Filesystems is available here: http://techblogon.com/android-file-system-structure-architecture-layout-details/#

Also, new files are not available until one removes the android device from the computer, and you reconnect it via USB.

Comment: so is it possible to record to the external (removable) sdcard, do we need to request some additional rights (something else beside WRITE_STORAGE)?